# 10 and 12 as the order of permutations in $S_7$

Tags: group-theory

> **Exercise**: Write all the values of $m\in\mathbb{N}$ so that there is permutation with order $m$ in $S_7$.

I tried to solve the question with the following proposition.

> **Proposition**: Let $\alpha\in S_n$. We have:
>
> 1) If $\alpha $ is a cycle of length(number of elements in the cycle) $K$ then $ord\alpha=k$.
>
> 2)If $\alpha$ is the product of disjoint cycles $\alpha=\theta_1,...,\theta_m$, so:

$ord\alpha=lcm(ord\theta_1...ord\theta_m)$.

I find the following values $m=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ according to 1).

However the solution gives a different answer $m=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,12\}$.

**Question:**

How can 10 and 12 be the order of some element in $S_7$, given the fact the maximum length(number of elements of cycle) is 7?(so I think).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: What is the order of the permutation $(1 2 3 4)(5 6 7)$?

Comment: It is 12. How do I find all the disjoint permutations?

Comment: Every permutation can be expressed as a product of disjoint cycles.  So what Steve Kass wrote can immediately be seen as such (a cycle of length 4 and one of length 3).  Since $7=2+5$, you should be able to answer the other part of your Question.

Comment: The possible sets of cycle lengths correspond to the ways of partitioning $7$ into integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, the product of cycles

$$(12)(34567)$$

is an element of order $10$ in $S_7$ and the product of cycles

$$(123)(4567)$$ is an element of order $12$.

To see why, you can compute it directly.  Or you can reason that since $(123)$ has order $3$, $(4567)$ has order $4$, and $(123)$ and $(4567)$ commute, the order of $(123)(4567) = \operatorname{lcm}(3,4)$.

In general for $S_n$, to answer this question you are looking for *partitions* of $n$.  That is, lists of whole numbers that add up to $n$.  For $n=7$, the partitions are $\{7\}, \{6,1\}, \{5,2\}, \{5,1,1\}, \ldots$ and so on.  Each of these corresponds with a choice of cycle sizes for a permutation in $S_7$: $\{7\}$ corresponds with permutations like $(1234567)$ and $\{5,2\}$ corresponds with permutations like $(12)(34567)$, etc.  The least common multiple of a given partition gives you the order of elements with the corresponding cycle decomposition.